# JavaFx PieChart: control size

Tags: charts, javafx

(I'm new to JavaFX.)

I'm adjusting an application developed in JavaFX that uses lots of pie charts depicted next to each other, all as children of the same `HBox`.

The charts don't have the same number of categories, and for some reason some of them become bigger than others.

Is there any way to control their radii? I would prefer all of them to have the same radius for some uniformity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though there is no public API to directly control the radius of the PieChart, but you can control it using the different public methods of [Region](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html).

The pie-radius depends on the Height and Width of the enclosing region. The radius when labels are absent is controlled by the following piece of code inside PieChart.

```
// Code from PieChart.java
if(!shouldShowLabels) {
     pieRadius = Math.min(contentWidth,contentHeight) / 2;
}
```

So you can use a combination of various [width](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#widthProperty) and [height](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#heightProperty) methods available to control the size of the pie chart. You can use min and max properties to specify min and max region space respectively.

Comment: That's pretty unfortunate, it seemed like something very natural to want to control. Thanks for the workaround!